# How to call a list of pure functions/pure vector function?

Tags: vector, code-review, pure-function

In one dimension, pure functions work as usual:

```
f = Function[{x}, 2 x]
f[a]
```

However, with a list of pure functions / a vector pure function this does not work with the same syntax:

```
g = {Function[{x}, 2 x], Function[{x}, 3 x]}
g[a]
```

does not give `{2a,3a}`, but `{Function[{x}, 2 x], Function[{x}, 3 x]}[a]` instead. So far, I worked aroud this by using `h[y_] = {g[[1]][y], g[[2]][y]}`, but that seems a bit awkward.

Comment: `Through`, `Comap`

Comment: This is the elegant alternative for my `h[y_]=...`, but is there a also a way to resolve this at the defintion of `g`?

Comment: Of course, the last syntax of `Comap`: `g = Comap@{Function[{x}, 2  x], Function[{x}, 3  x]}` Through can be used, too: `g = Through[{Function[{x}, 2  x], Function[{x}, 3  x]}@#] &;`

Answer (score 3):

```
g = {Function[{x}, 2 x], Function[{x}, 3 x]}
```

Using `Query`

```
Query[g] @ a
```

{2 a, 3 a}

```
Query[g] @ {2, 3}
```

{{4, 6}, {6, 9}}

As already commented by xzczd you can also use `Comap` (introduced with Version 14.0)

```
Comap[g] @ a
```

{2 a, 3 a}

Answer (score 3):

```
g = {Function[{x}, 2  x], Function[{x}, 3  x]};
```

---

Using `Thread`:

```
#1@#2 & @@@ Thread[{g, a}]

(*{2 a, 3 a}*)
```